# can't login with sll using curl anymore

Tags: ssl, curl, verify

Curl login with SSL was working fine before it broke down and driving me nuts.

Got following info with print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)):
My suspicion is "ssl_verify_result" because what i have read in the docs that if does not validate 'ssl certificate' then it throws out error '20'???

```
[url] => https://www.ooshirts.com/?module=artist&action=login
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 413
[request_size] => 329
[filetime] => -1
**[ssl_verify_result] => 20**
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 1.404
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0.265
[pretransfer_time] => 1.107
[size_upload] => 28
[size_download] => 485
[speed_download] => 345
[speed_upload] => 19
[download_content_length] => 485
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 1.404
[redirect_time] => 0
```

I am working on a local machine (win7X64) and downloaded SSL certificate from actual website and stored it locally in the same folder. It was working fine for couple of days but then started returning the same login page again. Below is a my test code:

```
$username="username"; 
$password="******"; 
$url="https://www.ooshirts.com/?module=artist&action=login"; 
$cookie=getcwd()."\cookie.txt"; 
$open = fopen($cookie,"w");
$postdata = "name=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\www.ooshirts.com");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;
fclose($open);
```

Any help???

Answer (score 0):

If problem is with SSL verification, the following settings will help you

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

The user name and password transmitted will still be SSL encrypted.
**Edit:** Just make sure you urlencode the post data as found [here](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post).